# Kubernetes ElasticSearch Helm Pod not going green

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes

I have Kubernetes configuration defined in .yml files and using EKS on AWS. Also I installed ElasticSearch helm chart. The pod is there and working, I can query elastic and get results, but the pod is not going green. Do you have any ideas what to check next?
Here is the screenshot of the pod:

[image]

[image]

Comment: please provide the pod's logs. (the screenshot is not informative since the messages didn't fit to the screen)

Answer (score 0):

Changing a parmeter in the .yaml file solved it.

from:

```
clusterHealthCheckParams: wait_for_status=green&timeout=1s
```

to:

```
clusterHealthCheckParams: "local=true"
```